# moving records by getting the specific number's prefix

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I want to segregate some records to another file in bash.

I have two files, one that contains all the records which is FILE_A and another that contains possible prefixes (FILE_B) of the numbers contained in FILE_A.

With the values of FILE A and B below, I want to move the records from FILE A that has prefixes contained in FILE_B. Please take note that I must compare **11th to 19th digits** of FILE_A only.
To further understand my query, please refer also the output below.

Thank you.

```
 $cat FILE_A
 xxxxxxxxxx234575234xxxx01234
 xxxxxxxxxx755602188xxxx02345
 xxxxxxxxxx044664690xxxx04567
 xxxxxxxxxx044663581xxxx01234
 xxxxxxxxxx082550123xxxx08234

 note: num=11th to 19th digit
```

file that contains num_prefix

```
 $cat FILE_B
 04466358
 0446646
 02345
 08234

 note: num_prefix=all the values above
```

OUTPUT:

```
 cat new_generated_file
 xxxxxxxxxx234575234xxxx01234
 xxxxxxxxxx044664690xxxx04567
 xxxxxxxxxx044663581xxxx01234
```

It is important that the script may only compare the 11th-19th digit of File_A to File_B because the last 5-digit may affect the output.

Like this one:

```
 $ sed 's/^0//' File_B > File_C; grep -f File_C File_A
```

gives me this output

```
 xxxxxxxxxx234575234xxxx01234
 xxxxxxxxxx755602188xxxx02345
 xxxxxxxxxx044664690xxxx04567
 xxxxxxxxxx044663581xxxx01234
 xxxxxxxxxx082550123xxxx08234
```

(xxxxxxxxxx755602188xxxx02345 and  xxxxxxxxxx082550123xxxx08234 were not supposed to be there)
because 08234 02345 (last 5 digits) are both in File_C

Comment: `x` ar also digit ? is xxxxxxxx99234599xxxx also elligible for 02345 prefix (assume not, pre_fix mean starting i guess) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -f <(sed 's/^0//' fileB) fileA
xxxxxxxxxx234575234xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx044664690xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx044663581xxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx082340123xxxxx
```

**Update:**

```
sed 's/^0//' fileB > fileC
while read -r f; do
    `echo "$f" | cut -c 11-19 | grep -qf fileC` && echo "$f"
done < fileA
```

**Update 2:**

```
sed 's/^0//' fileB > fileC
cut -c 11-19 fileA | grep -f fileC > fileD
grep -F -f fileD fileA
```

Comment: Is there any other way to expedite the process? Because it seems too slow to process large records. thanks

Comment: the output was only `234575234` instead of the whole line `xxxxxxxxxx234575234xxxx01234`

Comment: the output was only `234575234` instead of the whole line `xxxxxxxxxx234575234xxxx01234`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/ksh
sed -n '/^*$/ !{s/^0\{1,\}/0*/;s/^/^.{10}/;p;}' fileB > /tmp/CleanPrefix.egrep
egrep -f /tmp/CleanPrefix.egrep fileA
rm /tmp/CleanPrefix.egrep
```

- Should also work for bash (without the first line to stay in bash)
- It use a (e)grep regex as selector to avoid interference with surrounding content
- Assuming the fileA is always starting with 10 char (any printing char)
- Adapt to allow number starting with 0 to be with oy without in the fileA
- posix sed compliant so use `--posix` option on GNU sed

Comment: why does it gives me an output like ^.{10}468664 to fileB?

Comment: it is a regex expression used by egrep telling: select the line with any 10 first char followed by 468664. So `abcdefghij468664blabla' is take but not ' ab468664ij999999blabla` by egrep

Comment: have you tried it already? I run the script but I got no output

Comment: post adapted for the starting 0 in fileB that are sometimes present and sometimes not, also remove the case of blank line in fileB that will report all the line.